# How to create multi-pane layout in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make screen in which I have used multi pane layout.In screen ,left side show custom list view and right hand side show detail about click item.When I have run app in protrait from that show only single screen for example list.But on lanscape mode that is show list and detail page  on screen.Please suggest me what can i do or example.

Comment: You should have two folders in res for your layouts:
layout - for portrait layour xmls
layout-land - for landscape

Answer (score 6):

This is fairly easy with [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

And I think this is exactly what you want.

*Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0 (API level 11), primarily to support more dynamic and flexible UI designs on large screens, such as tablets.*

[image: Android developer example]

**TIP:**

***If you update your SDK, and ADT plugin for Eclipse (If you are using it). You can even create a new project based on a fragment example! Which is very informative and easy to adjust.
You project has to have a minimum SDK version of 11.***

Normally it would check with a [configuration qualifier](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) if you have a small handset screen or a big tablet screen, this check is fairly easy to find in your example project (Sorry I don't have much time to find a good example for you).  Now you can change this  configuration qualifier from `large` to `large-landscape`, or whatever you want.