# How to make a Multi-pane landscape layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to make a Multi-pane landscape layout with MainActivity (ListView) and DetailsView (ViewPager)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of tutorial available

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial.html

[How to create multi-pane layout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643910/how-to-create-multi-pane-layout-in-android)

[DrawerLayout and Multi Pane Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445309/drawerlayout-and-multi-pane-layout)

Comment: if its helpful for you then please click for helpful